# ggplot: Legend truncated after saving as .jpeg

Tags: r, ggplot2, jpeg, legend

I try to create stacked bar plots with my data in `ggplot`.
The result in the Java GD active window looks fine, but after saving it as `jpeg` (or `pdf` or `tiff`), the legend is truncated.
I managed to put the legend in the upper left, but then the legend's box will be truncated after saving.
Any idea for this? Thanks!

`run under r console/ jaguar/ R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386` (32-bit)

```
ggplot(data=ilc_fusion, aes(x=ASMA_dich_deu, fill=CD34_deu)) +
geom_bar() + 
labs(x="ASMA+ Myofibroblasten", y="Anzahl") + 
labs(fill= "Anteil CD34+ Fibrozyten") + 
scale_fill_brewer()
```

Alternative code:

```
ggplot(data=ilc_fusion, aes(x=ASMA_dich_deu, fill=CD34_deu)) +
geom_bar() + 
labs(x="ASMA+ Myofibroblasten", y="Anzahl") + 
labs (fill= "Anteil CD34+ Fibrozyten") + 
scale_fill_brewer() + 
theme (legend.justification=c(0,1), legend.position=c(0,1))
```

This is how it looks like in the Java Window:

[image]

And this is how it looks like after saving as jpeg:

[image]

and

[image]

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Did you use `ggsave()`?

Comment: Perfect, now it's looking as it should. Thanks a lot! :-)